# Do we need a separate tag for Numenera Discovery?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

Someone originally asked about this in a comment on the question: [Getting artifacts with XP and crafting artifacts with iotum in Numenera](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169112/getting-artifacts-with-xp-and-crafting-artifacts-with-iotum-in-numenera)

---

Should we have different tags for *Numenera* and *Numenera Discovery*/*Destiny*?

*Numenera Discovery* and *Destiny* are  two products which make substantial changes to the game *Numenera*. Monte Cook Games has said these are not a new version, but the answer to questions may differ based on whether the querent is interested in the "original" *Numenera* or *Discovery*/*Destiny* rules.

Some examples:

- *Destiny* includes a new cypher crafting system and rules for running communities. This is a big change as it allows a sense of "progress" instead of slowly decaying world that the players have to endure.
- *Discovery* includes a large number of changes to existing character features.

In Monte Cook Games's [own words](https://www.montecookgames.com/numenera-discovery-and-destiny/):

> *Numenera Discovery* is a revision of the original *Numenera* corebook, which will soon be out of print. *Numenera Discovery* improves the clarity of the game rules and dramatically increases the options available to players. [...]
>
> But this isn’t a new edition. There have been no substantive changes to the way the game plays mechanically, or the way NPCs, creatures, cyphers, artifacts, and other items work. And the setting isn’t changing either. This means you can keep using your bestiaries, adventures, card decks, character portfolios, and books like Into the Night, Technology Compendium, and Jade Colossus, and we will not issue any “second editions” of our supplements. And you can use future supplements with the existing *Numenera* corebook, if you choose to keep using it instead of *Numenera Discovery*. You don’t even have to make any changes to your current character—although you’ll now have more options as your character advances.

Should we have a separate tag for *Numenera Discovery*/*Destiny*?

Comment: Do you play this game? If so, what do you think?

Comment: Related: [Do we need more Mutants and masterminds edition tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/do-we-need-more-mutants-and-masterminds-edition-tags), [Convention for sub-tags within a game system](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/convention-for-sub-tags-within-a-game-system). I'm not familiar with either version (beyond knowing *of* them), but it may simply come down to a question of "are they different enough editions from one another to warrant specific tags?" (and/or "are there enough questions about either/both to need differentiation?").

Comment: Given that the quote says "There have been no substantive changes" to mechanics or setting, and that existing options in *Numenera* can still be used in *Numenera Discovery* without issue, it seems like a separate tag is not necessary (and instead such clarifications would be specified in the body of the question, if necessary). It's also possible that Monte Cook Games' description of the changes is slightly inaccurate, and that the mechanics changes are meaningful enough to justify a separate tag. But I leave that judgment to someone more familiar with the game than I am.

Answer (score 7):

### Suggestion: add the tags.

My instincts are that adding a tag won't hurt; it appears from some modest looking into this topic is that adding those tags to a Numenera question where applicable, and making sure to make points on what sources are used *in the text of the question*, will ensure that answerers will be able to identify what they need to answer.

If, over time, the tags cause trouble or confusion we can burninate them.

Aside: since the core rules, as it were, are going out of print my guess is that Monte is being somewhat cagey here.